# Deserialize json with same key but different type in android using Jackson

Tags: android, json, jackson

I am calling web-services which can have 2 types of json object in response. Now sometimes i get key `profile` with type String and sometimes it may have same key with type 'ProfileSubObject'. So how to manage this case? Below are my two types of object. I am using Jackson library to parse json.

1.)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "profession": "iOS Developer",
      "thanks": {
        "count": 5
      },
      "profile": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

2.)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "profession": "iOS Developer",
      "thanks": {
        "count": 5
      },
      "profile": {
        "val1":"test1",
        "val2":"test2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Key `profile` have 2 different type of object based on web-service call.

Following is my data class structure.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DataObject {

 @JsonProperty("profession")
private String profession;

@JsonProperty("profile")
private ProfileObject profile;

@JsonProperty("thanks")
private ThanksObject thanks;

public String getProfession() {
    return profession;
}

public ThanksObject getThanks() {
    return thanks;
}
public ProfileObject getProfile() {
    return profile;
}

}
```

And Profile class is as per below.

```
public class ProfileObject {

ProfileObject(){

}

ProfileObject(ProfileSubObject profileSubObject){
    this.profileSubObject= profileSubObject;

}

ProfileObject(String profile){
    this.profile= profile;
}
private  ProfileSubObject profileSubObject;
private String profile;

public ProfileSubObject getProfileSubObject() {
    return profileSubObject;
}
 }
```

Now when i parse my object, `ProfileObject` is always null. I want it to get parsed based on `proifle` key data type.

Anyone could help me with parsing?

Comment: do you mean that in the case of `"profile": "test"` then it is a sub profile?

Comment: @Sharon Ben Asher Edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In constructing the solution, I faced two problems:

1. the Json structure does not match a single `DataObject`
2. the original problem of deserializing same property into differnt types of Java objects.

The first problem I solved by constructing `JavaType` objects which tell Jackson the generic type of the collections involved.  There are two such collections: a `Map`, consisting of a single entry with key `"data"` and value of `List` of `DataObject`s

The second problem, I solved with the Jackson feature of `@JsonAnySetter` which directs Jackson to call a single method for all properties it doesn't recognize. For this purpose, I added `@JsonIgnore` to the profile variable to make sure that Jackson indeed doesn't recognize it.  Now Jackson calls the **same** method for the two input jsons

This is the new `DataObject` class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DataObject
{
    @JsonProperty("profession")
    public String profession;

    @JsonIgnore // forcing jackson to not recognize this property
    public ProfileObject profile;

    @JsonProperty("thanks")
    public ThanksObject thanks;

    public String getProfession() { return profession; }
    public void   setProfession(String p) { profession = p; }

    public ThanksObject getThanks() { return thanks; }
    public void         setThanks(ThanksObject t) { thanks = t; }

    public ProfileObject getProfile() { return profile; }
    public void          setProfile(ProfileObject p) { profile = p; }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setProfileFromJson(String name, Object value)
    {
        // if value is single String, call appropriate ctor 
        if (value instanceof String) {
            profile = new ProfileObject((String)value);
        }
        // if value is map, it must contain 'val1',  'val2' entries
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            ProfileSubObject profileSubObject =
                    new ProfileSubObject(((Map<String, String>)value).get("val1"), ((Map<String, String>)value).get("val2"));
            profile = new ProfileObject(profileSubObject);
        }
        // error?
    }
}
```

Here is my test method, which includes the java type construction I mentioned:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try (Reader reader = new FileReader("C://Temp/xx2.json")) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // type of key of map is String  
        JavaType stringType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(String.class);
        // type of value of map is list of DataObjects  
        JavaType listOfDataObject = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, DataObject.class);
        // finally, construct map type with key and value types  
        JavaType rootMap = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(HashMap.class, stringType, listOfDataObject);

        Map<String ,List<DataObject>> m = mapper.readValue(reader, rootMap);

        DataObject do1 = m.values()
                // get first (only?) value in map (it is list)
                .stream().findFirst().orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                // get first (only?) item in list - it is the DataObject
                .stream().findFirst().orElse(null);

        System.out.println(do1.profile);
        System.out.println(do1.profile.profile);
        System.out.println(do1.profile.profileSubObject.val1 + " " + do1.profile.profileSubObject.val2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this assumes that there are no other additional properties but good explanation!!

Comment: Of course the solution is tailoerd to the information provided. You can fine grain the input by questioning the type and contents of the key and value arguments

Comment: @Sharon Ben Asher Thank you so much for your quick solution and explanation,

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help in regards to parsing JSON, use a JsonReader. It does assume you are using RESTful webservice and have already gotten a HttpURLConnection and an InputStream from the connection.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html