# How to handle two data types coming in same response for same parameter name

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I am calling a third-party API that returns two different values for the same parameter name as below,

```
    ActivationResponse activationResponse = new ActivationResponse();
ResponseEntity<ActivationResponse> response = null;
    response = restTemplate.exchange(Url, HttpMethod.POST, request, ActivationResponse.class);
    activationResponse = response.getBody();
```

Error response:

```
    {
   "executionCode":"2",
   "executionMessage":"NullPointerException Occured!",
   "response":"java.lang.NullPointerException"
}
```

Success response:

```
{
  "executionCode" : "0",
  "executionMessage" : "SUCCESS",
  "response" : {
    "orderID" : "79966036"
  }
}
```

As the sample response `response` parameter can come as a string or with a JSON object.

Currently the response model is as below,

```
public class ActivationResponse {

    private String executionCode;
    private String executionMessage;
    private ActivationResponseDetails response;
}

public class ActivationResponseDetails {
    private String orderID;
}
```

When the error comes, an exception is thrown indicating that it can't handle the `response` parameter. Please advice how to handle both success and failure scenarios without issues.

Please Note that approach in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670341/deserialize-json-with-same-key-but-different-type-in-android-using-jackson) is not possible, because I have to print the logs in following way, so using `@JsonIgnore` will not show that parameter on the log.

Logs are printed like this,

```
log.info("ActivationResponse json : {}", mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response.getBody()));
```

Comment: Must it be deserialized to a single type? Is it impossble that success maps to OkResponse and errors to ErrorResponse?

Comment: Just for clarification: The problem occurs because there is no orderID?

Comment: @morsor success response maps without error. But error response gives an exception. I think it is because in error scenario it is expecting a json object but receiving a string.

Comment: @SirHawrk in error scenario, "response" parameter comes as a string, not a json object. I want to know how i can handle both success and error scenarios without getting exceptions

Comment: @cmb28: Yes - I understand that is the problem. My questions is whether you MUST map ALL responses to the exact same structure? It is perfectly normal to have success and error map to different types

Comment: @morsor yes it is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on having a one-size-fits-all Response object, setting the type of the response field to Object, may do the trick:

```
public class ActivationResponse {
    private String executionCode;
    private String executionMessage;
    private Object response;
}
```

The field 'response' should now resolve to a simple String (success) or a more involved Java object (error).

Comment: Thnanks for the reply. Actually I want to do the opposite of this. keep response as "private ActivationResponseDetails response;" and ignore the string values coming

Comment: Can you just not have your caller map the success response to a String and the error response to ActivationResponseDetails? Could you please explain why both responses apparently MUST map to the same object?

Comment: This idea of using the Object field solved my problem. Often the Json attributes may come as JsonObject or JsonArray with the same name, and this was the right solution for me to avoid errors in both scenarios! I also created then a method to get the field as a List<String>, just by using some conditions and casting operations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219012/5538923